# Problem with literal $ when using sequalize.fn after upgrading to 6.13 from 5.21

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a raw query containing 'include' of the form

```
[{
    model: UserGroup,
    attributes: ['name',
        'enabled',
        'attributeData',
        [sequelize.fn('JSON_VALUE', sequelize.col('UserGroup.attributeData'), "$.path"), 'path']
    
    ],
    required: false
}]
```

With version 5.21 ... this led to a proper query being generated.  Now, with 6.13, the generated query contains

```
JSON_VALUE(`UserGroup`.`attributeData`, '$$.path')
```

See that the second parameter to JSON_VALUE is `$$.path` instead of `$.path`.

How can I prevent the extra dollar sign from being added?

Thanks,

Comment: Escaping like `\$.path`?

Comment: First thing I tried ... didn't work.  Thanks

Comment: Maybe `$$.path` then?

Comment: That was the second thing I tried :-)

Comment: Can you mention all your tries in the post?

Comment: that was it.  $$ , \$  ,  \\$

Comment: `Sequelize.escape`?

Comment: no luck.  thanks for the idea

Comment: Can you try to wrap it to Sequelize.literal?

Comment: That seems to do the trick !! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `Sequelize.literal` to pass a value as is.

```js
sequelize.fn('JSON_VALUE', sequelize.col('UserGroup.attributeData'), sequelize.literal("'$.path'"))
```

Comment: this solves the issue. why did @mlg not accept this answer?

Comment: I can't say for certain, maybe he got the answer from my comment above and stopped watching this question.